# Making requests to AWS Gateway API React Native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-api-gateway

In my app, the user can authenticate via AWS Cognito User Pools or Facebook all managed an AWS identity pool. That's all working correctly, the user can login and authenticate successfully. Now, I need to make authenticated requests to an AWS Gateway API which will then trigger Lambda functions. I'm confused as to what comes next. Do I need to write code to sign these requests or does the AWS javascript SDK already have something built in for this? Do I need to create an Authorizer? How do I go from AWS.config.credentials to making successful, authenticated requests to a Gateway API?

I'm using React Native so the auto generated APIs won't work.

EDIT: Here's my request code:

`fetch('https://MY_API_GATEWAY_URL/prod/handleMessages/', {
        method: 'GET',
        body: null,
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.token, /* this is the JWT token from AWS Cognito. */
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
      })`

I get 403 response from this with the exception: IncompleteSignatureException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you should have a valid Cognito issued JWT. To call APIs behind AWS API Gateway you need to pass the JWT along with your API calls. This should go in the Authorization header with type of Bearer. You can determine whether a custom authorizer is necessary or just use the built in authorization with API Gateway.

Additional info can be found here -
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

You also need to ensure IAM rules are in place to allow the UserPool to access the API Gateway endpoints - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated my question with some code. When I do what you said I get an exception. Going to look into it, but just wanted to verify that I've done everything I need to. Maybe there's a permissions issue in AWS. Also, if I want to use the default authorizer, do I need to configure anything for that to work?

Comment: You likely need to setup IAM permissions to allow for the user pool to access the API - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Comment: Doing some more reading, AWS.config.credentials contains an accessKeyId and and secretKey. Would it be better to use those to make requests and let IAM handle permissions instead of an authorizer. This would allow me to allow users from any identity provider access the API, no? Because not only do I have Cognito User Pool users, but also Facebook and perhaps more like Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AWS Amplify library's API module which will automatically sign requests: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

For React Native this is available via npm:

```
npm install aws-amplify-react-native
```

If using Cognito User Pools link the library as outlined here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/quick_start.md#react-native-development

The API module will have you configure a friendly name for your endpoint and also the Invocation URL from an API Gateway stage. Then you simply call the HTTP method and pass optional parameters as options:

```
import Amplify, {API} from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
Amplify.configure('your_config_file_here');
API.get('apiname', 'invokeURL', options).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: most likely you will use `import Amplify, { Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';`

Comment: link to document: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js#manual-setup-import-existing-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the JWT token from Server-side, after AWS Cognito UserPools Authentication, using a API Gateway Endpoint. e.g `/<stage>/authenticate`

```
var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Password : 'password',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
    ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
};
var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
        console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});
```

For more details, check [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).

After the authentication send the jwtToken back to the React Native app, where it needs to be sent in Authorization header with the token for subsequent API requests.

At API Gateway configure user pool authorizer in integration method configuration, so that it will automatically validate the authorization header and load user context information for the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doing some more reading, AWS.config.credentials contains an accessKeyId and and secretKey. Would it be better to use those to make requests and let IAM handle permissions instead of an authorizer. This would allow me to allow users from any identity provider access the API, no? Because not only do I have Cognito User Pool users, but also Facebook and perhaps more like Google.